# what is the difference between normal function and self invoking function - JS

Tags: javascript

I'm learning Javascript

What is difference between these two codes as they both return the same output

```
var getcode = function(){
    var apicode = '0]Eal(eh&2';
    return apicode;
}
getcode();
```

```
var getCode = (function() {
  var apiCode = '0]Eal(eh&2';   

  return function() {
    return apiCode;
  };
})();

getCode();
```

Comment: In this case? Basically no difference.

Comment: the one is a function expression and the other one is a Immediately Invoked Function Expression

Comment: 2 . Function or snippet will help us to securing and restricting the scope of function and their value within itself Immediately Invoked Function Expression

Comment: The second has more scopes than the first one. (-_^)